# Power Query data load: large dataset causes 'expression.error column not found'

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

When I try to load the query below with the entire data set (ie, around 100,000 rows in total) it errors with:

**"Expression.Error column "Column1" not found"** *(Column1 refers to a column which I expanded in a function and then call in the query)*

When I limit the dataset to call only ~900 rows, **I do NOT get the error** and the dataset loads perfectly.

My conclusion is that there is NOT ACTUALLY an error in my query, but somehow the size of the dataset is causing this.

---

> QUESTION: How can I prevent this error and get my whole dataset to
> load?

---

***********QUERY THAT DOES NOT LOAD:**

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "FnGet", each FnGet([companyID])),
#"Expanded FnGet" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Invoked Custom Function", "FnGet", {"date", "articleUrl", "title", "summary", "reads"}, {"date", "articleUrl", "title", "summary", "reads"}) in
#"Expanded FnGet"
```

*******QUERY THAT HAS NO ERROR ON LOAD:
NOTE STEP 1 "Kept First Rows" which reduces the dataset to approx 1000 rows****

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Kept First Rows" = Table.FirstN(Source,10),
#"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Kept First Rows", "FnGet", each FnGet([companyID])),
#"Expanded FnGet" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Invoked Custom Function", "FnGet", {"date", "articleUrl", "title", "summary", "reads"}, {"date", "articleUrl", "title", "summary", "reads"}) in
#"Expanded FnGet"
```

*************** ADDITIONAL INFORMATION ******************

The query references a function **"FnGet"** which references Column1 in step 3:

```
let
Source = (companyID as any) => let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://www.lexology.com/api/v1/track/clients/articles?companyId=" & Number.ToText(companyID)&"&limit=100" , [Headers=[ApiKey="ABCD12345"]])),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    Value = #"Converted to Table"{7}[Value],
    #"Converted to Table1" = Table.FromList(Value, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table1", "Column1", {"date", "articleUrl", "title", "summary", "reads"}, {"date", "articleUrl", "title", "summary", "reads"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```

in
Source

Comment: Is your `companyID` unique from the `Table2` in excel? If not, you can call the function with a unique list of `companyID` reducing the overload of the API in your function. Also, it's likely you are hitting the limits in your API, so you need to wait after each call, half a second or so, depends on the limits. Chris Webb has a really good piece about that https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2015/04/30/using-function-invokeafter-in-power-query/

Comment: Thanks this was helpful and lead me to a solution @AngeloCanepa